# Truffle revert when deploying contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

solidity newbie here working on moving from remix to truffle suite. I have a contract that worked fine on remix but is raising the following error message when attempting to deploy to local test chain using truffle:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert    at PromiEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/promievent.js:9:1)
    at Function.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:120:1)
    at lastCompletedMigration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:198:1)
    at Object.lastCompletedMigration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:209:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Truffle v5.1.14 (core: 5.1.14)
Node v13.8.0
```

I gather that this is probably related to the `require` statements in my contract. Full contract code below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Azimuth {

    function getSponsoringCount(uint32) external view returns (uint256) {}

    function sponsoring(uint32, uint) public returns (uint32) {}

}

contract Subscriptions {

    Azimuth azi = Azimuth(0x0baB5299383880A1282F481402b72696Caa2025D);

    address payable internal owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Error: not the contract owner.");
        _;
    }

    mapping(uint32 => uint256) internal balances;
    uint32[] internal subscribers;

    /// import subscriber list
    function importSubscribers(uint32 _point) internal onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < azi.getSponsoringCount(_point); i++) {
            subscribers.push(azi.sponsoring(_point, i));
        }
    }

    mapping(uint32 => bool) internal blacklist;

    function addBlacklist(uint32 _point) public onlyOwner {
        blacklist[_point] = true;
    }

    function unBlacklist(uint32 _point) public onlyOwner {
        blacklist[_point] = false;
    }

    /// check whether a point is a valid subscriber
    function isSubscriber(uint32 _point) internal view returns (bool _isSubscriber) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < subscribers.length; i += 1) {
            if (subscribers[i] == _point) {
                _isSubscriber = true;
            }
        }
        return _isSubscriber;
    }

    /// add a new subscriber, initialize their balance as the value sent, and send payment to contract owner
    function subscribe(uint32 _point) public payable {
        require(isSubscriber(_point) == false, "Error: this point is already a subscriber.");
        subscribers.push(_point);
        balances[_point] = msg.value;
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    /// receive payment from subscriber, update their balance, and send payment to contract owner
    function pay(uint32 _point) public payable {
        require(isSubscriber(_point) == true, "Error: this point is not a valid subscriber.");
        balances[_point] += msg.value;
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    /// check subscriber balance. TODO: allow point owner to access this balance as well
    function checkBalance(uint32 _point) public view onlyOwner returns(uint _balance) {
        require(isSubscriber(_point) == true, "Error: this point is not a valid subscriber.");
        return (balances[_point]);
    }

    /// bill the subscribers
    /// a default billing rate of zero (no charge)
    uint internal billingRate = 0;

    /// is it desirable to automate this?
    function bill() public onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < subscribers.length; i += 1) {
            if (balances[subscribers[i]] < billingRate) {
                boot(subscribers[i]);
            } else {
                balances[subscribers[i]] -= billingRate;
            }
        }
    }

    /// boot a subscriber
    function boot(uint32 _point) public onlyOwner {
        balances[_point] = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < subscribers.length; i++) {
            if (subscribers[i] == _point) {
                delete subscribers[i];
                break; /// check whether this is correct
            }
        }
    }

    /// adjust the billing rate
    function setRate(uint _amount) public onlyOwner {
        billingRate = _amount;
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciate any help or direction in figuring this out!

Comment: What command is being executed? The error message is not enough, does it has more output? The constructor doesn't do anything so it is unlikely for it to be the culprit, do you do anything else in the migration scrips?

Comment: as @Ismael said. Even I feel that there is an issue in the migration scripts or the truffle-config.js